# How to overcome mathematics-related anxiety?

Tags: student-motivation, anxiety

I'm in undergrad engineering, freshman year, in IT. I suffer anxiety when I have to do calculus. Trigonometry is just tortuous. Anyone got any tips for lessening that? I guess hard work is the best, but anything else? Anyone else had any personal experiences of the same sort?

Comment: My best suggestion is to prepare yourself with a formula sheet and do as many exercise as you can put your hands on using that formula sheet. Mathematics at your level is not about sudden insights or the ability to see solution through inference from other areas. Although it is good that you should be able to derive the trigonometric relations, as you will certainly not be allowed to bring an formula sheet to the exam room, when practicing don't get stuck on the minor details and focus on the bigger picture.

Comment: I'd recommend migrating this question to math.stackexchange, since it's about mathematics rather than academia in general.  (I think few, if any, other academic fields create the same type or level of anxiety that math does.)

Comment: Social science uses maths a lot less. Perhaps anthropology.

Comment: Take a look at this [lovely text](http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/2013/04/25/were-all-bad-at-math-1-i-feel-stupid-too/) about math anxiety in a mathematician!

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant Trigonometric ratios in Multivariable Calculus is what gets to me, but your suggestion is gratefully accepted.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician I'm a newbie to stack  exchange, and I kinda felt that this sort of anxiety was more related to Academia, but I guess you have a point too, so I'll see how to migrate this post and do so (in a bit).

Comment: @Ana thank you, that was a very nice read. I feel like I'm in the same place, just not in Topology but in Calculus. And I don't see myself being able to ask the professors about anything like the writer did. Nevertheless, the words ring forebodingly true, and I  suppose I should just crack on.

Comment: @DaveClarke I'm not quite sure if I can understand  what you're saying. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: I'm saying, perhaps you could do something with a lot less maths instead.

Comment: @DaveClarke Well, I wanted to go for journalism, but, uh.. where I live, parents usually decide what's best for their children.

Comment: @SurajZala Yes and make sure that the formula is short (one page front and back) and HAND WRITTEN. This is the most important part because you might even start learning about why the formula become what they are as you jog them down. Practice with it as much as possible so there wouldn't be any error in the formulas.

Comment: @scaaahu I'm new here, so I thought this would be a good place to ask (I am much more concerned with the anxiety part than with the mathematics part, which led me to my assumption). I just read the info on migrating a question, and since it says questions that have been answered are best not migrated as the migration would be pointless, I've chosen not to. I'd close this question if I could, I got great answers.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Actually, a better  place for migration is [matheducators.se]: their about page says, "The community welcomes questions on [...] the process of learning mathematics at all levels" so this is perfectly on-topic, there. I've flagged for migration.

Comment: @scaaahu (ping. See my previous comment on migration location. It really should be possible to ping more than one person in a comment.)

Comment: @SurajZala We don't like to close questions that could have a good home *somewhere*; we like to keep good questions (like this one!) around so they can help future users, and so that more people can contribute answers if they want to. Would you like me to migrate this question for you? If so, to which site ([math.se] or [matheducators.se])?

Comment: @ff524 That's quite kind of you. I think Mathematics Educators would be a proper place for this question, so, could you migrate it there, please?

Comment: This question has been asked on this site before, albeit from the perspective of teachers. While it doesn't directly address your question, you might find some of the methods listed in the answers as helpful: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/194/267

Comment: I would urge the OP **not** to accept an answer so hastily; I think the question (i.e. as stated in the title) is very broad, and has the potential to generate many (possibly better, but certainly different) responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try doing homework with friends.  I used to have pretty bad programming anxiety and it got a lot better when I coded with other people.

The caveat is you don't want to do problem sets with friends who are much better at math than you, because then you will just feel discouraged when they get all the answers before you do.

Comment: Practicing with friends does seem like a pretty good idea, but I can only go for that next semester, since this one ends in a couple of weeks. I might have to make some new friends though, the ones I have right now are pretty much aces at this stage in calculus.

Comment: @SurajZala: Come to class ten minutes early, then introduce yourself to the person next to you and ask "want to work on homework 1 together?"  Works best if s/he isn't already sitting with friends.

Comment: I'm not sure if that'd work exactly so, but suggestion appreciated and I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes our past experiences pile up, and create anxiety from the stories we tell ourselves about how bad we are at something, or how often we mess it up. One way to lessen anxiety is to do a guided visualization, telling ourselves more positive things.

My students often say they blanked on a test, even though they felt like they really knew the material. So I created [a guided visualization for relaxing with math study and math tests](http://mathmamawrites.blogspot.com/2009/09/math-relax-guided-visualization-for.html). Check it out, and see if it helps any. (Though working with others may be more helpful in your situation.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on my own experience, the only way to overcome math anxiety is to realise that it's a beautiful subject that can be applied to an enormous amount of areas and applications, a subject that makes you a more powerful thinker and problem solver. Until you do that, you will always be sort of afraid of it. This is, of course, easier said than done.

I used to be afraid of math at some point in my life, mainly due to the fact that I had bad teachers. When I was in college, however, I had a few really good professors who somehow managed to convince me that math is amazing; I've been excited about the subject ever since.

I would suggest reading a couple of math-related books in your free time, such as "Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions" by Edwin Abbott Abbott, "How to Think Like a Mathematician: A Companion to Undergraduate Mathematics" by Dr Kevin Houston, "One Two Three ... Infinity: Facts and Speculations of Science" by George Gamow, and other related books. These will help you create a positive attitude towards math, which in the long run will allow you to look at it from a different perspective, i.e. not as a scary subject that you need to pass, but as an amazing area that is worth exploring.

Once you have this positive attitude, solving problems will become much easier and your hard work will be transformed into more effective work.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I do realize how fantastic mathematics is, and I love seeing it in effect outside. I am also about 30+% through with Flatland, coincidentally, and it is quite ( for lack of an apt word at the moment) fun. I almost bought a copy of One Two Three ... Infinity this weekend too. I guess I'll just have to push myself harder.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to thank you. I apologize. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my teaching years (34), many times, the anxious students would come up to me and say: "I don't understand anything." My work was not mainly to give them an answer, but of helping them find out exactly what they didn't understand so that they could 1) focus on what they don't understand and 2) use what they did understand to advance their work.

Maybe you could make a list of what you find easy and what you find difficult. You could also add to every subject of this list if you understand the element or not. You may find out that there are subjects you find easy but don't understand; don't worry about that for the moment.

Armed with this list, try to figure out how you could prepare yourself for an exam. You could also build an exam in which you think you'd have a perfect score. Also, try to identify in your list the subjects you think you could better understand by reading your textbook and/or doing more exercises. Then identify the subjects where you think a friend could help you out. And finally identify the subjects for which only your teacher could come to your aid and go see him or her with questions pertaining to those subjects. Prepare your questions in writing; read them over to be sure you'll be asking the questions that are important to you and that the teacher will understand you.