# Problem solving approach to learning and psychology

Tags: self-learning, problem-solving, psychology

I try to have a problem solving approach to learning math. What i mean by this is if someone sets some questions or problems regarding the material i am reading how should i answer or what questions or problems should i make from the material i am reading to help me in learning,

But, i confuse it with problem solving generally. Generally, i have tested my skills on problem solving and sometimes i fail to solve some problems. Probably i should not confuse these two ways or approaches?

Also, what should i do to feel better about math and learning and not feel like having fear or sadness?I have read if i remember correctly that in the United States of America, many people have fear and sadness about learning and math and this affects me at least a little i think.

Generally, i read undergraduate material in math and i try some papers which are uploaded on arxiv from researchers. Sometimes, i read free material uploaded from other sources.

Comment: It looks like you are asking two questions - one about problem solving and one about anxiety, perhaps? Of course, these two can affect each other, but maybe it is better to split these up and post a second question on fear/anxiety.

Comment: You might also want to check whether your question is answered in whole or in part elsewhere on Mathematics Educators, e.g. https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10679/376

Comment: When i am in a classroom with a teacher that is teaching i feel better, probably no sadness and no fear. Also, this i think impoves my abilities and performance. Perhaps i should imagine having a teacher and being in a classroom with other students to help me in self learning?